# error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/"

Tags: devops, package.json

I am trying to build the react app with docker compose and it is giving me this error even though the package.json file is lying in the same directory where I am building the image..

Building app
Sending build context to Docker daemon  27.65MB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:16.12 as build
---> 3b66eb585643
Step 2/8 : COPY package*.json app/
---> Using cache
---> 81ef3445e340
Step 3/8 : RUN yarn install
---> Using cache
---> ab7ec97e90cd
Step 4/8 : COPY . app/
---> Using cache
---> 5d67b3211ad4
Step 5/8 : RUN yarn run build
---> Running in 27abf0824b6f
yarn run v1.22.15
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
The command '/bin/sh -c yarn run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed

It is the complete error

Please let me know what can be the solution

Comment: Can you post an image of your folder structure please?

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: root@ip-10-0-0-216:~/kasheery-react# ls
Dockerfile  README.md  config-overrides.js  docker-compose.yml  jsconfig.json  kasheery-app.rar  nginx  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  public  src  yarn.lock